# How to debug system freeze?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, freeze

I'm experiencing strange bug when I close lid of my laptop - system freezes (no reaction on keys, no response form ssh) hard and displays some strange colour effects. The kernel log (after reboot) shows nothing. My question is - how to debug it? Maybe there's a way to track last called kernel function or something similar?

Comment: Which laptop model is that? 
Does disabling suspend-on-lid-close help?

Comment: Similar problem here, I also wonder this question. `Kernel 2.6.32-5-686`

Comment: It's Dell Studio 1555. I don't need any workarounds, I want to fix this problem :).
If someone's interested how display looks after freeze:
[1] http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22768404/DSC_0011.JPG
[2] http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22768404/DSC_0012.JPG
The rectangles are blurring and moving.

Comment: Which is the video card on this laptop and what driver you are using for it?

Comment: ATI Radeon 4570, Catalyst. Btw., fixing this particular problem is not the subject of the question, rather debugging system freeze :)

Answer (score 1):

The kernel probably did log some information, but they never made it on time to the disk. If your laptop has got a serial port, set the kernel to use it as console (add `console=ttyS[X]` as boot option); you will see the messages there from another machine as it happens. If not, you can use an Ethernet port and try netconsole.

In general, you have a problem with suspending you machine, which happens quite often. There a several guides on the internet about debugging it [see here](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.txt) or [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend).

Comment: Yeah, and this link can be useful: http://wiki.openvz.org/Remote_console_setup